# POST Method in Feathers Example

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

Can someone explain, how I make a POST method using Feathers and test it in postman. I notice that there are two parameters, "data" and "params". What are their differences? Can someone give me a complete example how to create POST method in feathers and test it in postman?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **data** is the actual data passed to the service method, ex: a form data. and the **[params](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params)** contains the provider (i.e REST, Socket.io or Primus), connection details, authenticated user details and other info related to that service.

For [post](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#createdata-params)  method you can use the **create(data, params)** method of the service that you are calling and do your post activity there like creating records like below.

```
app.use('/messages', {
  messages: [],

  create(data, params) {
    this.messages.push(data);
    // Your post activity here
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }
});
```

And in postman use can use the URL http://localhost:3030/messages and in the request body provide the JSON you want to pass as a data to the POST method

ref: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html